# How do you query MongoDB by pairs of keys using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of pairs of things, of the form e.g. `[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D']]`. I want to query `MongoDB` for records in a specific collection which have properties matching both of these things.

For example, here is what I would want to get back:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('...'),
  'first_property': 'A',
  'second_property': 'B'
 },
 {'_id': ObjectId('...'),
  'first_property': 'C',
  'second_property': 'D'
 }]
```

How do I query *simultaneous* properties using `pymongo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got pretty good performance out of the following pattern:

```
client.find({'$or': [{'property_a': value_a, 'property_b': value_b} for value_a, value_b in some_list_of_two_element_tuples]}
```

This creates a very long [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) statement out of our requested tuples.

Comment: Wouldn't this iterate through the for loop every time pymongo returns a data chunk? Wouldn't it be easier to do `cursor = client.find({'$or': [{'property_a': value_a, 'property_b': value_b},{'property_a':1,'property_b':1});` then iterate through said cursor?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your comment, as it does not appear to be semantically correct. Are you missing a `]`?

Comment: Yes, it should. I was just wondering if you should get the cursor first instead, then iterate.